# Looking for some help identifying an AT90USB646-based board

Tags: atmel

I inherited this single board computer a while back - clearly some kind of developer board that has LEDs, I/O ports, two USB ports, an 8x8 LED matrix, buttons, sound, SD card slot, etc - like a super Arduino of sorts.

Unfortunately, not a single identifying name, mark or number on it that I can find!  It does have an [Atmel AT90USB646](http://eecs.oregonstate.edu/education/docs/datasheets/at90usb.pdf) main processor.

Also, it comes in a blue plastic project box with a board layout diagram on it, plus programming instructions...

> To Program:
>
> 1. Connect 'Programming USB' to Computer
> 2. Press both 'Programming Button' and 'Reset Button' at the same time
> 3. Release the 'Reset Button' first

Can anyone identify it from this picture?

[image: Mystery Board]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wunderboard rev 1, by Oregon State University](http://eecs.oregonstate.edu/education/hardware/wunder.1/). They have a newer version 2 with some changes, but same microcontroller.

Links on that page are out of date.
[Schematic](http://eecs.oregonstate.edu/education/docs/wunder.1/schematic.pdf)
[Silkscreen](http://eecs.oregonstate.edu/education/docs/wunder.1/silkscreen.pdf)
[User Guide](http://eecs.oregonstate.edu/education/docs/wunder.1/wunderguide.pdf)
[Course 1](http://eecs.oregonstate.edu/education/courses/cs151/) and [Course 2](http://eecs.oregonstate.edu/education/courses/cs152/) links, with curriculum and file links.

[Youtube Defender game On Wunderboard.1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rx4XSNmcca8) 
[Youtube PDA controlling Wunder.1 LED Matrix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5C-d7JZ9-EU)

For future reference, all I did was google `AT90USB646 Development Board`. And then checked Google Image Results for that phrase.

Comment: Ah hah!  In fact I live in Corvallis so this makes sense.  RE: Google.  I'd tried some variations on that, but hadn't seen it - even did a direct "find this image" search with the board, but all it gave me were crowds of people :)

Comment: @TimHolt ah that's because GIS doesn't do "similar" pictures, it looks for basically the same image. Unless someone took the same exact picture, minus some minor color/brightness difference, it wouldn't come up. But the fourth row down for me (because google results always vary by person) gave this picture https://admtn.ucsadm.oregonstate.edu/ustores/web/images/store_8/wunder.1_small.jpg which while isn't on the OSU's web store page any more, gave me the name, I took it from there.